# Crystal Report Parameter Issue

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am using this code to generate the Crystal Report into PDF. All the while it was working. But suddenly I got this issue:

> Unable to cast object of type 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterDiscreteValue' to type 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterValue'.

at this line of code:

```
crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);
```

I am using C# .NET :

```
            ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            cryRpt.Load("F:\\Crystal Reports\\SYSPEX_INVOICE.rpt");

            new TableLogOnInfos();
            TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo;
            var crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();

            ParameterFieldDefinitions crParameterFieldDefinitions;
            ParameterFieldDefinition crParameterFieldDefinition;
            ParameterValues crParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
            ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

            crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = Convert.ToString(DocEntry);
            crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
            crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["@DOCENTRY"];
            crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;

            crParameterValues.Clear();
            crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);
            crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);

            crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "SYSPEXSAP03";
            crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "SYSPEX_LIVE";
            crConnectionInfo.UserID = "sa";
            crConnectionInfo.Password = "Password1111";

            var crTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
            foreach (Table crTable in crTables)
            {
                crtableLogoninfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
                crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
            }



            ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
            DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
            PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();

            CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "F:\\eInvoice\\65ST\\" + DocNum + ".pdf";
            CrExportOptions = cryRpt.ExportOptions;
            {
                CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
                CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
            }
            cryRpt.Export();

            // Email Part
```

Answer (score 0):

Check CrystalDescision.CrystalReports.Engine and other Crystal libraries to see if their version match up.

Source:[here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24460374/Unable-to-cast-object-of-type-'CrystalDecisions-Shared-ParameterDiscreteValue'-to-type-'CrystalDecisions-Shared-ParameterValue'.html)